# Кракозябры вместо кириллицы из JSON в java

Tags: java, json, кодировка, кириллица

Есть небольшая программа на JavaFX(Maven). С бесплатного сервиса получаю JSON в ответ на запрос. В нём есть строка на кириллице, когда достаю её и вывожу в консоль (для проверки) - всё выводится без нареканий, а при выводе этой строки на Label в окно приложения отображаются кракозябры. С латиницей проблем нет. Всё остальное (long, double) тоже вынимается без проблем. Весь остальной текст в окне приложения на кириллице тоже в порядке. Сам JSON выводится в консоль и читается без проблем. В POM файле кодировку прописывал дополнительно(`<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>`), хотя автоматом она там задаётся(`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`). Вытаскивал строку из JSON через .get и .getString результат тот же. Как избавиться от кракозябров?
Часть кода:

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(outPut);
   cityInfo.setText(obj.getString("name"); //кракозябры
   System.out.println(obj.getString("name")); //всё норм
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показывайте, как именно выглядят Ваши коякозяблы.

Comment: Какой графический API используете? Какой шрифт используется для меток? Есть ли в этом шрифте кириллические юникодные символы?

Comment: Если в консоли все выводится, то сервис, json и его парсинг тут ни при чем. Строка получена и с ней все в порядке. Проблема в том, как приложение использует строку. Что таке `cityInfo`?

Comment: cityinfo - это id лейбла (label) в окне приложения на javaFX. Весь остальной текст на кириллице в окне отображается корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Переписал без Мавена и проблема исчезла.